# recover list of checkbox

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox

I am trying to use jquery mobile, I want to retrieve the list of checked box. Here is my code to populate the list of checkbox:

```js
for( var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++  ) //Remplir tableau liste des identifiants étapes
    { 
         $('#lbtn2').append("<input    type='checkbox' value="+
               results.rows.item(i).Phrase+
               "  name = "+results.rows.item(i).QuotationParDefaut+
               "   id="+results.rows.item(i).idPhrase+" />");
         $('#lbtn2').append('<label for='+
               results.rows.item(i).idPhrase+'>'+
               results.rows.item(i).Phrase+'</label>');
    }
```

And here is the code that allows to retrieve the list of selected labels.

```js
$("#lbtn2 input:checked").each(function()
{
   tab_phrase_selectionner[j] = 
       $("label[for='" + ( $(this).attr("id") ) + "']").text();//Pour le fichier A1.js
   j++;
});
```

The problem is that if I select six checkboxes it returns only 3 checkboxes. Anybody have an idea about this problem?

Comment: Please, format your code and, if possible, create a jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Your code is working just fine for me. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/EtrgA/) based on your code. Might be something with the values in your `results.rows`. Show final markup after rendering in browser for your checkboxes.